# Google Vision Color For Each Object

Tags: api, google-cloud-vision, google-vision, vision

Is there any chance to know dominant colors for every single object in Google Vision API. I can see the dominant colors for the whole image but can't find for every single object.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned dominant color indeed exist just for the whole image, it's image properties.

"The Image Properties feature detects general attributes of the image, such as dominant color."

[enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-properties)